# Are there any Quantum Computing degrees in Germany, Quebec, or The USA?

Tags: resource-request

I am an Electrical and Computer Engineering student from Egypt and was considering venturing into the realm of Quantum Computing. I really want to take part in the next info revolution and I have taken some online courses towards that end, but that is not enough, I believe.

I was thinking of having that education in Germany, because it is affordable, very excellent and close to home, or French Canada or The USA. However when I search for Masters or PhDs in the field I only get sham sites and I get that many universities have Quantum Computing interest and research groups but I can't find degrees or subspecialization or even individual courses that can aid in bridging the gap of knowledge.

So does anybody know any universities that offer such degrees or courses?

Comment: Is this on topic for this website?

Comment: I don't really know. I saw a similar question on another stack exchange but the answers weren't relevant though. I put my bets on the site.

Comment: The concern is that this is a question about your career, and not about quantum computing. Anyway, a quick google search reveals https://www.physik.uni-heidelberg.de/?lang=en and https://www.imprs-quantum.mpg.de/ How hard are you looking?

Comment: Why Québec, specifically?

Comment: I know they have top notch universities, and really I just like the  general atmosphere there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially a "shopping" question which falls in the [career advice](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/26) category.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta But I don't know where to ask. I don't know where to start.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit?

Comment: @MarkS It'd be a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/defining-shopping-questions) there too...anyway, things can still be discussed in the comments here. However, it can be boiled down to a resource-request question perhaps, if they make it more specific...like restricting to a specific country and mentioning the exact criteria they're looking for.

Comment: An attempt at an answer: I am not aware of any degrees specific to quantum computing, and my company is looking to hire someone into quantum computing! But you can, as a cofounder of mine is currently doing, write your thesis in quantum computing if you find a willing advisor. Likely actual study courses would be in computer science or physics.